# initializing a value to a structure

Tags: c

```
  struct mac_filter
    {
        char ether_dhost[6];
        char ether_shost[6];
        short ether_type;
    };

    struct packet_filter
    {
        struct mac_filter mac;
    };

    main()
    {
    struct packet_filter test;
    test.mac= NULL;
    }
```

i get

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct mac_filter’ from type ‘void *’
```

here i want to initialize all the member function of mac_filter to zero, is there any way to set them to zero instead to initializing each member functions to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your question correctly but default initialization is doing just what you want:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct mac_filter test = { 0 };
}
```

By default that initialization sets all fields recursively to the "correct" form of `0`. In most cases this is equivalent to `memset` but you never know what your target architecture has as specialities.

And if you want to assign to that part (this is something different than initialization) you may use a "compound literal" from C99:

```
test.mac = (const packet_filter){ 0 };
```

BTW, the code that you posted is completely bogus. The type of your declaration is not correct and your definition of `main` is ridiculous. Please post code that is as correct as possible so we can concentrate on the actual problem for the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your struct contains an actual `struct mac_filter`, not a pointer to one. You can't assign `NULL` to it.

If you wanted a pointer to one, your struct would look like:

```
struct packet_filter
{
    struct mac_filter *mac;
};
```

To use it you would need to `malloc()` memory to it, or assign a pointer to it.

If you just want to zero out your struct, you use `memset` and pass a pointer to your struct:

```
memset(&test.mac, 0, sizeof (struct mac_filter));
```

Comment: if i have structure of 10 member functions how to set a only a few member function of a that structure to zero and leave the others.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow - what is "structure of 10 member functions" ?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually faster to `memset` them all to zero and then fill in the values as they become available later.

However I recommend you use [C99 initialization](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) when you know all the values:

```
struct packet_filter test = {
    .mac = (struct mac_filter) {
        .ether_dhost = {0, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55},
        .ether_shost = {0xff, 0xee, 0xdd, 0xcc, 0xbb, 0xaa};
    },
};
```

Any values you don't set are automatically initialized to zero. In this case I've left `mac.ether_type` as `0`.

Note that this kind of initialization is very popular with initializing C-style jump tables at both compile time and run time, among other kinds of arrays that are sparsely populated, or index/member fields being set are very specific.

Comment: initialization to `0` can and should (almost always) be done by simply using the fall back initializer. At least this is what this question is about as I understand it. Has the advantage to work for most dialects of C, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use memset:

```
memset(&test.mac, 0, sizeof (test.mac));
```

See [the manual page of the memset function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset).

Comment: if i have structure of 10 member functions how to set a only a few member function of a that structure to zero and leave the others.

Answer (score 0):

Use [memset](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.14.html#memset) in C

```
memset(&test.mac, 0, sizeof (struct mac_filter));
```

Comment: if i have structure of 10 member functions how to set a only a few member function of a that structure to zero and leave the others.

Comment: @asir : Member functions in C?

Comment: @asir : You can't define functions inside structure in C. C and C++ are two different languages.

Answer (score -1):

better you define it as global variable. and default value of global variable is zero.

Comment: don't do that. as if the only possibility to initialize a variable by default would be to make it static. Just initialize it. please see my answer.

Comment: Global variables should be hunted down and eliminated one by one. They are a very good way to turn any code into an unpredicable mess. There are very few good reasons to use a global variable - this is not one of them.